# Mount directory to docker container while using CWL (Common Workflow Language)

Tags: docker, workflow, pipeline

I'm trying to get a bunch of very big files into a docker container while using CWL. When using the default method of file-inputs via

job.yml:

```
input_file:
  class: File
  path: /home/ubuntu/data/bigfile.zip
```

the CWL runner somehow copies the file and gets stuck. Is there an easy way of just mounting a directory directly into a docker container?

task.cwl:

```
cwlVersion: cwl:draft-3
class: CommandLineTool
baseCommand: run.sh

hints:
  - class: DockerRequirement
    dockerImageId: name123

inputs:
  - id: input_file
    type: File
    inputBinding:
      position: 1
outputs: []
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Recent versions of the reference implementation's `cwltool` seem to take care of this automatically by creating Docker "volumes" for any files which need to be accessed from within the running container. [Rabix](http://rabix.io/)'s Executor also handled it without additional configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The CWL user guide has an example for how to do this: https://www.commonwl.org/user_guide/15-staging/index.html

You use `InitialWorkDirRequirement` and add the input file to the list of files to be staged in the working directory, like so:

```
cwlVersion: v1.0
class: CommandLineTool
baseCommand: cat

hints:
  DockerRequirement:
    dockerPull: alpine

inputs:
  in1:
    type: File
    inputBinding:
      position: 1
      valueFrom: $(self.basename)

requirements:
  InitialWorkDirRequirement:
    listing:
      - $(inputs.in1)

outputs:
  out1: stdout
```

When you run this, say with the CWL reference runner (`cwltool`), you can see that the input file is mounted directly in the working directory (but safely, in a ReadOnly mode):

```
[job step-staging.cwl] /private/tmp/docker_tmpIaCJQ8$ docker \
run \
-i \
--volume=/private/tmp/docker_tmpIaCJQ8:/XMOiku:rw \
--volume=/private/tmp/docker_tmpW2RR3v:/tmp:rw \
--volume=/Users/kghose/Work/code/conditional/runif-examples/wf1.cwl:/XMOiku/wf1.cwl:ro \
--workdir=/XMOiku \
--read-only=true \
--log-driver=none \
--user=501:20 \
--rm \
--env=TMPDIR=/tmp \
--env=HOME=/XMOiku \
--cidfile=/private/tmp/docker_tmpdV6afe/20190502114327-207989.cid \
alpine \
cat \
wf1.cwl > /private/tmp/docker_tmpIaCJQ8/f3c708b20abf7fbf7f089060ec071c0956eb0cfd
```

However, as @TheDudeAbides says, the behavior of CWL 1.0 is to mount the files and not copy them.  So even if you did not stage them, they would be mounted to make them available to the container, just in a different directory. This is how cwltool, toil and the SBG platform work.